# Arduino interfacing with GPS gy Neo 6Mv2

Tags: arduino, gps

I have written the following code. I want the string returned from the method

> displayInfo( )

to be updated and printed just once, but the method sends strings repeatedly. If I copy the same code in void setup( ) function it is not printing any value.

```
  #include <TinyGPS++.h>
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
  static const int RXPin = 12, TXPin = 13;
  static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;
  // The TinyGPS++ object

  TinyGPSPlus gps;


  // The serial connection to the GPS

  SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

  String msg="";

  String message="";


  void setup()

  {

   Serial.begin(9600);
   ss.begin(GPSBaud);

   }


  void loop()

  {

   while (ss.available() > 0)

   if (gps.encode(ss.read()))

   message = displayInfo();

   Serial.print(message);

   }


  String displayInfo()
  {
  if (gps.location.isValid())
  {
  String lati=String(gps.location.lat(), 3);
  String logi=String(gps.location.lng(),3);
  msg=lati+","+logi+"\n";
  return(msg);
  }
  }
```

I have updated the code to recover some of the errors like function returning value with a global variable but it still does not provide me a single String value even after I had put the void loop( ) code in void setup( )

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


static const int RXPin = 12, TXPin = 13;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);
String msg="";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);

  while (ss.available()>0)
   if (gps.encode(ss.read()))
    displayInfo();
     Serial.print(msg);

}

void loop()
{
  // This sketch displays information every time a new sentence is correctly encoded.


}

void displayInfo()
{
  //Serial.print(F("Location: ")); 
  if (gps.location.isValid())
  {
    String lati=String(gps.location.lat(), 3);
    String longi=String(gps.location.lng(), 3);
    msg="location: "+lati+","+longi+"\n";  
  }
  else
  { 
    msg=msg+"invalid";
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*: 
The ss (SoftwareSerial) has a buffer wich contains the data that is ready to be send. ss.begin() will return 0 in your setup since the buffer is still empty, therefore the while loop will not be iterated even once.

The loop() function of the arduino works like a while so by placing the content of that while loop, and replacing the while with an if, you will be able to keep testing until you have a message in the buffer.

By adding a boolean to check if you have already sent a message, you can make sure only 1 message will be sent.

```
  #include <TinyGPS++.h>
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
  static const int RXPin = 12, TXPin = 13;
  static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

  TinyGPSPlus gps;

  SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

  boolean sent = false;

  void setup()
  {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   ss.begin(GPSBaud);   
  }

  void loop()
  {
   if (ss.available()>0 && sent == false){
    if (gps.encode(ss.read())){
     String msg = displayInfo();
     if (msg != NULL){
      Serial.print(msg);
      sent = true;
     }
    }
   }
  }

  String displayInfo()
  {
   if (gps.location.isValid())
   {
    String msg="";
    String lati=String(gps.location.lat(), 3);
    String logi=String(gps.location.lng(),3);
    msg=lati+","+logi+"\n";
    return(msg);
   }
   else{
     return NULL;
   }
  }
```

By returning a NULL in the displayinfo()'s else statement, and testing for it within the loop(), you can ensure that you will only print a message when everything was working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have made the changes mentioned and still while calling the function from void setup( ) yields me no result.

Comment: Try putting a Serial.print within the while loop and if function with some text to see what's going on.

Comment: can you please mention the loop( ) method

Comment: Allright, i did some more reading to understand what you are trying to do. Put the content from the while loop into the loop() and replace this while with an if test. The loop() is in essence a while. By putting the while in your setup it will not print even once because your buffer starts with being empty so your ss.available will return 0.

Comment: Sorry but I am new to Arduino programming and I didn't undestand you properly. Can you please get me the code to use.

Comment: I have edited my answer, i believe this code will fix it.

Comment: Your answer code worked all fine, but the issue is it is executing only else part of the method displayInfo( )

Comment: I've edited my answer again, this time with a test so it will only show something when it got into the if of the method displayInfo().

Comment: Could you answer if the code worked as you desired? And if it worked, accept it as an answer?

Comment: The code is giving error that null is not declared in the scope.

Comment: try NULL instead, I'm used to programming in java where it is null.